# Using Google Maps API to route 2 locations in Hong Kong

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on a project that uses the google map api v3 to display a route from point A to B. I have noticed that some points in Hong Kong don't map correctly.

If I use maps.google.com site to look up a location, it looks up the address for the location and displays correctly. If I use the same location as the starting point it shows incorrectly.

Note the locations which have "normal" addresses with street numbers will show correctly. Is this a problem with the api mapping like the maps.google.site?

Code:

```
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();  

var request = {       
    origin: start,        
    destination: end,         
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[travelBy]      
    };           

directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {       
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {          
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }     
});
```

Note: "google.maps.TravelMode[travelBy]" gets populated from a dropdown of the different travel modes like DRIVING, WALKING, etc.

Comment: What are the addresses you are having trouble with?  Your problem sounds more like a problem with your input data than with the code.  Note that this "google.maps.TravelMode[travelBy]" doesn't look like a valid travel mode to me.

Answer (score 1):

[The Peninsula Hong Kong, Salisbury Rd, Kowloon, Hong Kong](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=The+Peninsula+Hong+Kong,+Salisbury+Rd,+Kowloon,+Hong+Kong&hl=en&sll=37.6,-95.665&sspn=34.596091,54.140625&hq=The+Peninsula+Hong+Kong,+Salisbury+Rd,&hnear=Kowloon,+Hong+Kong&t=m&z=14) is not a geocoder result (it isn't a postal address).

See this [entry in the FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#geocoder_differences) explaining the difference between Google Maps and the Google Maps API geocoders.  Google Maps combines many different data sources (Places, geocode information, search results, etc) to generate its results.